# В 1С почему код в отборе записывается после запросов?

Tags: 1с

Код:

```
НЗТовКомп = РегистрыНакопления.ПодарочныеДвижы.СоздатьНаборЗаписей();
НЗТовКомп.Отбор.Регистратор.Значение = ДокКорректировкаСсылка;
    
    Запрос = Новый Запрос;
    Запрос.Текст = 
        "ВЫБРАТЬ
        |   СерийныеНомера.Ссылка КАК Ссылка
        |ИЗ
        |   Справочник.СерийныеНомера КАК СерийныеНомера
        |ГДЕ
        |   СерийныеНомера.Владелец = &Владелец";
    
    Запрос.УстановитьПараметр("Владелец", Справочники.Номенклатура.НайтиПоНаименованию("Движ 1200р"));
    
    РезультатЗапроса = Запрос.Выполнить();
    
    ВыборкаДетальныеЗаписи = РезультатЗапроса.Выбрать();
    
    Пока ВыборкаДетальныеЗаписи.Следующий() Цикл
         
        СтрРег = НЗТовКомп.Добавить();
        СтрРег.Период                         = ДокКорректировка.Дата;
        СтрРег.Активность                     = Истина;
        СтрРег.ВидДвижения                     = ВидДвиженияНакопления.Приход;
        СтрРег.Регистратор                     = ДокКорректировкаСсылка;
        СтрРег.ПодарочныйДвиж            = Справочники.Номенклатура.НайтиПоНаименованию("Движ 1200р");
        СтрРег.НомерДвижа                = ВыборкаДетальныеЗаписи.Ссылка;
        СтрРег.Сумма                          = 1200;
                
    КонецЦикла;
    НЗТовКомп.Записать();
```

Здесь сперва идет: `НЗТовКомп.Отбор.Регистратор.Значение = ДокКорректировкаСсылка;` далее идет запрос, и только потом записывается: `НЗТовКомп.Записать();`.

Для чего служит: `НЗТовКомп.Отбор.Регистратор.Значение`? А что будет если сразу записать? До запроса.

Answer (score 1):

> А что будет если сразу записать? До запроса.

Вы запишите пустой набор с отбором по установленному регистратору. Все движения сотрутся.

Comment: по хорошему - нужно проверять перед записью в регистр (добавлялись ли записи) и если нет (запрос пустой) тогда не записывать !